# Data type mismatch in criteria expression ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: c#-4.0

Hi guys when I make a update or delete I get this error what should I do

```
OleDbConnection con = new 
 OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
 Application.StartupPath + "\\db\\it.accdb");  

    con.Open();

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    string query = "UPDATE data SET [Target Name]= '" +textBox1.Text+ "' where ID = '" + textBox9.Text + "' ";
    cmd.CommandText = query;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();               
    con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is to always use parameterized queries. After that check the type for Id, its probably an int so when you add that parameter make sure you add the value as an int type.

See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

> ### Remarks
>
> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used.

Code refactored

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + MediaTypeNames.Application.StartupPath + "\\db\\it.accdb"))
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE data SET [Target Name]= ? where ID = ?";

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@target", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = textBox1.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@id", OleDbType.Integer)).Value = int.Parse(textBox9.Text);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

---

Note that:

- OleConnection and OleDbCommand are wrapped in `using` blocks so they are disposed/cleaned up even when an exception occurs.
- Parameters are now used instead of hard coding the string values
- Parameters use the correct data types
- The id is converted to an `int` before it is assigned to the parameter, this is critical because otherwise it could be treated as a string which it is not (based on the root of your excption).